# Having trouble getting Miller-Rabin primality test in Python

Tags: python, math, primes

I have been trying to implement Miller-Rabin primality test in Python. Unfortunately there seems to be a problem on some prime numbers. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
def _isPrime(n):

if n % 2 == 0:
    return False

a = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41]
s, d = _Apart(n) # turns it into 2^s x d
print(s, d)

basePrime = False
isPrime = True

for base in a:
    if base >= n-2:
        break 

    if isPrime == False and basePrime == False:
        return False
    
    witness = pow(base, d)

    if (witness % n) == 1 or (witness % n) == (n-1):
        basePrime = True
        continue
    else:
        basePrime = False

    for r in range(1, s):
        witness = pow(base, pow(2, r) * d)

        if (witness % n) != ( n - 1 ):
            isPrime = False

return True
```

Test:

```
isPrime(17)
```

Expected:

```
True
```

Result:

```
False
```

Comment: The `_Apart()` function is critical, but you haven't shown your implementation. Other than that your logic is wrong at `if (witness % n) != ( n - 1 ):  isPrime = False`. That's not how the test works. The correct behavior for the loop over r is: if base\*\*(d * (2\*\*r)) mod n = -1 then `base` is a witness and you must try the next base. Otherwise, you have to increase r by 1 and try again. Only if it *never* becomes -1 in the r-loop can you declare the number composite.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Miller Rabin test that is deterministic, no need for random numbers. This implementation is for python 3.7. In python 3.8, llinear_diophantinex can be replaced with pow(x, -1, y).  Also i used gmpy2 as it's very fast, but you can just replace the gmpy2 statements with normal pow if you can't use that, and just remove the gmpy2.mpz() wrappers since those are just used to overload operators.

```
import gmpy2

sinn = 2110229697309202254897383305762150945330987087513434511395506048950594976569434432057019507105035289374307720719984431280856161609820548842778454256113246763860786119268583367543952735347969627478873317341364209555365064365565504232770227619462128918701942169785585423104678142850200975026619010035331023744330713985615650556129731348659986462960062760308034462660525448390420668021248422741300646552941285862310410598374242189448623917196191138254637812716211329113836605859918549332304189053950819346551095911511755911832183789503704294770046935064469435830299623205136625543859303686699678929069468518950480476841246805908501510754550017255944080874819287974625925494008373883250410775902993163965873632474224574883242826458163446781002284368017611606202344050570737818087202137703099075773680753707346415849787963446390136517016131227807076254668461445862154978026041507116570585784569893773262639243954090283224759975513502582494002154146757110676408972377044584495342170277522887809749465855954126593100747444378301829661568735873345178089061677917127496915956539418931430313218084338374827152407795095072639044306222222695685778907958272820576498682506540189586657786292950574081739269257159839589987847266550007783514316481286222515710538845836151864127815058116482680058626451349913138908040817800742009650450811565324184631847563730941344941348929727603343965091116543702880556850922077216848669966268219928808236163268726995495688157209747596437162960244538054993785127947211290438554095851924381172697827312534174244295581184309147813790451951453564726742200569263225639113681905176376701339808868274637448606821696026703034737428319530072483125495383057919894902076566679023694181381398377144302767983385253577700652358431959604517728821603076762965129019244904679015099154368058005173028200266632883632953133017055122970338782493475762548347258351148037427739052271661340801912188203749647918379812483260399614599813650518046331670764766419886619324840045611486524123102046413946014624119568013100078163986683199814025915420877588778260860713148420321896163326473203441644820182490479899368048072263481024886708136521847014624735722333931331098969321911443978386868675912141648200500219168920887757573018380579532261231821382787339600631297820996466930957801607217549420247654458172818940238337170577825003408756362106088558651381993611741503374243481167926898332728164900189941804942580426055589622673679047058619682175301326905577843405270203660160407401675700528981573327582844330828861745574031416926871562443652858767649050943181353635950301154441954046214987718582670685455252774874198771086552440702483933126644594300464549471422237478151976561680719370424626162642534252062987911763456822609569209140676822858933588602318066530038691463577379331113471591913447226829868760176810195567325921301390329055242213842898142597360121925124635965685365925901913816717677946911762631634793638450106377437599347740569467683272089859392249351406815344105961234868327316964137925419770514177021722214309784062017826024217906664090209434553785436385765927274067126192143337589109608949427467825999057058702263715338956534536892852849984934736685814891286495169007648767081688963426768409476169071460997622740467533572971356017575900999100928776382541052696124463195981888715845688808970103527288822088031150716134784735332326775370417950625124642515148342694377095213470544739900830244879573205335578256682901821773047071352497997708791157012233232529777513203024818391621220967964874173106990772425289900446640237659116713251437567138729645677868024033209183367071421651937808005637679844370347367922676824239404492688418047080583797577102267329067247758368597488680401670673861120323439239792549053895366970423259196919428554146265587250617656401028722578111927104663315250291888502226235291264834968061065817079511872899991276288365723969841290984981957389126603952133124328219936785870274843554107325931034103072894378438818494802517594594270034007832922248742746517915210656205746338575621725899098414488628833412591266637224507533934158213117522503993423240638893845121918647788013


def llinear_diophantinex(a, b, divmodx=1, x=1, y=0, offset=0, withstats=False, pow_mod_p2=False):  
  origa, origb = a, gmpy2.mpz(b)  
  r=a   
  q = a//b  
  prevq=1   
  if a == 1: 
    return 1 
  if withstats == True:  
    print(f"a = {a}, b = {b}, q = {q}, r = {r}")    
  while r != 0:   
       prevr = r   
       a,r,b = b, b, r    
       q,r = divmod(a,b)  
       x, y = y, x - q * y  
       if withstats == True:  
         print(f"a = {a}, b = {b}, q = {q}, r = {r}, x = {x}, y = {y}")   
  y = gmpy2.mpz(1 - origb*x // origa - 1) 
  if withstats == True:  
    print(f"x = {x}, y = {y}")   
  x,y=y,x  
  modx = (-abs(x)*divmodx)%origb  
  if withstats == True:  
    print(f"x = {x}, y = {y}, modx = {modx}")  
  if pow_mod_p2==False:    
    return (x*divmodx)%origb, y, modx, (origa)%origb 
  else:  
    if x < 0: return (modx*divmodx)%origb  
    else: return (x*divmodx)%origb 
 
def ffs(x): 
    """Returns the index, counting from 0, of the 
    least significant set bit in `x`. 
    """ 
    return (x&-x).bit_length()-1 
 
def MillerRabin(arglist):  
  N = arglist[0] 
  primetest = arglist[1] 
  iterx = arglist[2] 
  powx = arglist[3] 
  withstats = arglist[4] 
  primetest = gmpy2.powmod(primetest, powx, N)  
  if withstats == True: 
     print("first: ", primetest)  
  if primetest == 1 or primetest == N - 1:  
    return True  
  else:  
    for x in range(0, iterx):  
       primetest = gmpy2.powmod(primetest, 2, N)  
       if withstats == True: 
          print("else: ", primetest)  
       if primetest == N - 1: return True  
       if primetest == 1: return False  
  return False  
       
def sfactorint_isprime(N, withstats=False): 
 
    N = gmpy2.mpz(N) 
    from multiprocessing import Pool 
 
    if N <= 1: return False 
    if N == 2: 
      return True 
    if N % 2 == 0: 
      return False 
    if N < 2: 
        return False 
         
    # Add Trial Factoring here to speed up smaller factored number testing 
 
     
    iterx = ffs(N-1) 
    """ This k test is an algorithmic test builder instead of using 
        random numbers. The offset of k, from -2 to +2 produces pow tests 
        that fail or pass instead of having to use random numbers and more 
        iterations. All you need are those 5 numbers from k to get a  
        primality answer.  
    """ 
    k = llinear_diophantinex(N, 1<<N.bit_length(), pow_mod_p2=True) - 1 
    t = N >> iterx 
    tests = [k-2, k-1, k, k+1, k+2] 
     
    for primetest in range(len(tests)): 
      if tests[primetest] >= N: 
         tests[primetest] %= N 
   
    arglist = [] 
    for primetest in range(len(tests)): 
      if tests[primetest] >= 2: 
        arglist.append([N, tests[primetest], iterx, t, withstats]) 
      
    with Pool(5) as p: 
       s=p.map(MillerRabin, arglist)     
     
    if s.count(True) == len(arglist): return True
    else: return False 
     
    return s
```

Comment: *...All you need are those 5 numbers from k to get a primality answer...* That would be quite an achievement, but I don't see any reason to believe it's true. Do you have a proof of this claim?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I also tried to implement this algorithm in the deterministic form, as shown in [Miller Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Miller_test), and ran into the same problem. I couldn't figure out why it failed for some numbers so I decided to implement the 'complete' [Miller-Rabin Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_test) and it worked.

I should warn that it gets slow quickly as `n` increases. It's advised to use some numeric library like [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) to optimize the calculations.

With some tweaks on your code it can be achieved:

```
import random

def _isPrime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    rounds = 40  # Determines the accuracy of the test
    s, d = _Apart(n)  # Turns it into 2^s x d + 1

    for _ in range(rounds):
        base = random.randrange(2, n-1)  # Randomly selects a base
        witness = pow(base, d)

        if (witness % n) == 1 or (witness % n) == (n-1):
            continue

        for _ in range(1, s):
            witness = pow(witness, 2) % n

            if witness == (n-1):
                break
        else:  # if the for-loop is not 'broken', n is not prime
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: If the Miller Test didn't work then your code had a bug. As this code looks correct at first glance it can be easily adapted for the Miller Test. A couple of other points: numpy does not support integers larger than 64-bits, so it may not be a good choice; the `pow()` function built in to python has a 3-argument form that uses an efficient algorithm to perform modular arithmetic. Your `pow(base, d)` line will be too slow and memory intensive for large values of d. It's much faster to compute `pow(base, d, n)`. I understand you want your code to match OPs as closely as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime(n):
    """returns True if n is prime else False"""
    if n < 5 or n & 1 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
        return 2 <= n <= 3
    s = ((n - 1) & (1 - n)).bit_length() - 1
    d = n >> s
    for a in [2, 325, 9375, 28178, 450775, 9780504, 1795265022]:
        p = pow(a, d, n)
        if p == 1 or p == n - 1 or a % n == 0:
            continue
        for _ in range(s):
            p = (p * p) % n
            if p == n - 1:
                break
        else:
            return False
    return True
```